# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html - not in HTML header

Tags: html, css

Although there are other answers relating to this question on Stack Overflow I couldn't find one fitting my situation.

I'm working on a site for a client, and there is this error in the console log when inspecting with chrome dev tools:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.pelviva.com/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css".
```

The dev area on my own domain works fine - [here](http://dev.a00.cc) - but is having issues on the clients hosting [pelviva.com](http://www.pelviva.com/).

The css file it is accessing is imported in the main style.css file on line 2:

```
@import url(font-awesome.min.css);
```

...and so is not linked in the html header.

Another strange thing is the two links to the css. The URL on pelviva.com links to a version of the index without any CSS where as on my dev subdomain it is the plain text off the minified CSS:

[Client no CSS URL](http://www.pelviva.com/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css)

[Dev minified CSS](http://dev.a00.cc/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

!update

The guys running the server solved it. No sure what they did, but it's done now. The code was fine, must have been a config error.

Comment: http://www.pelviva.com/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css - How does this url show me an HTML page? it's supposed to show me a CSS file. You seem to have errors there `Unexpected token <`

Comment: Make sure your CSS file `font-awesome.min.css` contains the actual fontawesome code... You have html code there which happens because you downloaded it from github or something like that.

Comment: @AdamJarvis Are you using Apache as application server? Any .htaccess files configurated in your folders?

Comment: @odedta I have no idea, I am not a back end developer. But the server guys fixed it on their end. Oh and it was the HTML from the index, not github. I'm not *that* careless.

Comment: Not seeing any HTML in the CSS file.

Comment: Weird, seems ok now.

Comment: @hungerstar it's been resolved now. Still not sure what the cause was.